# How to prevent cURL being fired twice in a WP function?

Tags: php, wordpress

When a WordPress post is published, the publish_post hook is sometimes called multiple times.
Therefore the function send_webhook is also triggered multiple times.

I tried to prevent it with a global variable, but this does not seem to work. I think that's because the function itself is called multiple times.

This is my code:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'send_webhook');
function send_webhook($post_id) {
    global $ss_done;
    if (!isset($ss_done)) {
        $url = 'https://hook.integromat.com/wy41cb1vlsfi7m1dfef63sxec3wotdnr';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $ss_done = true;
    }
}
```

How can I prevent cURL being triggered multiple times in, for example a time period of 300 seconds, even when the function is called multiple times? Maybe somehow store the post title in a variable and then check if its already used? Any ideas?

Comment: I would look into [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/). You can store data to the transient subsystem, and WordPress will automatically prune the database of expired ones. For instance, you could do something like `set_transient( 'maurice_cache_' . $post_id, [] , 300 );` The value doesn't really matter, only the ID in your case. For most simple sites this is good enough, however it is possible for items to be evicted from the cache sooner, and if that's a problem, you should look at options or post_meta instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/) to validate if the function has been called before. If it wasn't (or if 300 seconds has passed), perform the api call and save the current time:

```php
add_action('publish_post', 'send_webhook');
function send_webhook($post_id) {
    $last = get_post_meta($post_id, 'integromat_webhook_sent', true);
    if (empty($last) || (strtotime('now') - strtotime($last)) > 300  ) {
        $url = 'https://hook.integromat.com/wy41cb1vlsfi7m1dfef63sxec3wotdnr';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'integromat_webhook_sent', strtotime('now'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Lucius. This looks like a great solution indeed. I will try that now and let you know.